# Using pattern image as font color in Sketch

Tags: text, sketch-app

In Sketch, I'm trying to set the fill of a piece of text as a pattern image, rather than a solid color.

Don't see the option for it in Sketch 3.3.3, is there another method or a Sketch plug in I can use to do this?

(I'm a novice Sketch user, so appreciate everyone's help in advance.)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out on my own. Posting it on here for reference:

1. Select textbox
2. Layer > Style > Select Fill
3. Select Pattern Image as Fill type